# the deleteRows function is populating my Google Sheet with 500 blank rows

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The below trigger works great, but when executed it repopulates my sheet with 500 rows. After the trigger is executed I need it to only show the 1st row.

```
function deleteRows() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet 1'); 

var start, howManyToDelete; 

start = 2;

howManyToDelete = sheet.getLastRow() - start + 1;
}
```

Comment: you can (and should) put your code between \`\`\` quotes to format them so that it looks nicer :)

Comment: Your code seems uncomplete. I do not see any statement to delete rows

Comment: All good I solved the issue. I changed the 'start = 2;' to 'start = 3'. This generated the titles and only one empty row to begin working form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer in the comments from the original poster:**

> All good I solved the issue. I changed the 'start = 2;' to 'start = 3'. This generated the titles and only one empty row to begin working form